# How to create alias in SQL Server 2022

Tags: alias, sql-server-2022

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16:

> The SQL Server Native Client (often abbreviated SNAC) has been removed from SQL Server 2022 (16.x) and SQL Server Management Studio 19 (SSMS). The SQL Server Native Client (SQLNCLI or SQLNCLI11) and the legacy Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) are not recommended for new development. Switch to the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver (MSOLEDBSQL) for SQL Server or the latest Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server going forward.

I used to create aliases using the SQL Server Configuration Manager, but since SQL Server 2022, the form to create alias has all the fields disabled:

[image: Alias - New]

**How do I create alias in SQL Server 2022, is that even possible?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still possible to create SQL Server aliases by using these programs instead of the Configuration Manager:

- `C:\Windows\System32\cliconfg.exe` (64bit),
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cliconfg.exe` (32bit)

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly.

Comment: Upvoted (thx!) but just gonna ask... What the odds are that SysWOW64 has the 32-bit version, and System32 has the 64?

Comment: jokes aside, I submitted a fix to this helpful answer

Comment: @Wellspring thank you

Comment: @Wellspring Actually, you are wrong. My original answer was correct. `SysWOW64` does actually contain the 32-bit version, and `System32` the 64-bit version even if it's counterintuitive.

Comment: Proves my google spot-check came up short! (I did check!) I saw the explanation, "The System32 folder is often used by 32-bit programs, while 64-bit programs use the SysWOW64 folder" and drew the wrong conclusion. Thanks, @TomPažourek